# Configure project-specific workflow without global admin permission

Tags: jira

As far as I understood the way Jira works, workflows are defined on a global level and require the global "Jira Administrator" permission to administer them. Having the "Administrator" role for a project only seems not to be sufficient to edit a workflow that is assigned to this project (via a workflow schema).

In practice, I've experienced that those people who have the global administration permissions are not really "motivated" to care about the configuration of individual projects, especially when there are dozens of them.

The project admins, however, very much like to adjust workflows and other things for their project. The global Jira admins, however, are not willing to put project admins into the "Jira administrator" group, which is, after all, quite reasonable.

A typical result is that all projects run more or less the same way, and all the wonderful configuration features of Jira remain unused.

Is there a way to allow people which don't have the global admin permission but do have project administration role to change workflows and other stuff for *their* project(s) only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it is impossible to do in current Jira version. 
You can vote and watch this issue here https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-3156.
Hopefully they will implement it soon.